# fetch rows data with same values in two column

Tags: php, mysql

I tried this : 
this code :

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT t_no,cust_name
FROM menu_order
WHERE b_id IN (
    SELECT b_id,m_name
    FROM menu_order
    GROUP BY b_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)";


$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row =  mysql_fetch_array($result);

     echo $row['t_no'];
     echo $row['cust_name'];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $name = $row['m_name'];
    $n = explode(',', $name);
    foreach ($n as $d) {
        if ($d !== '') { // because before first comma or after last can be empty
            echo $d.",".PHP_EOL;

        }

    }

}
```

Please can any one tell how to fetch data with `t_no(table number)` in common in php.
Here, `b_id(booking_id) is foreign key`.

**Expected Output is**:

```
1    |T03  | 2017-08-07 | Dal Fry,Sahi Paneer,Aloo Paratha | 2,1,1
```

> Here is the database:

[image]

Comment: what you tried so far ??

Comment: add in question

Comment: try this query `SELECT DISTINCT t_no,cust_name,b_id,m_name
FROM menu_order
WHERE b_id >= 1`

Comment: this query gave all the data of that table.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: are you getting any result usimg this query in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT b_id, t_no, date, GROUP_CONCAT(m_name), GROUP_CONCAT(quantity)
FROM table
GROUP BY b_id, t_no, date;
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) MySQL'd documentation for `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource <- this is what I'm getting as output.

Comment: @PriyaNage can you try this query in MySQL admin?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your query.. your sub query will return two columns including name, but the `b_id IN()` would only require b_id. Remove `m_name` from your sub query.